# Simplifying road network for cartography?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, road

How do I simplify and merge segments of a complex network for cartographic purposes?

As you can see, i have a lots of segments and i want to merge and simplify to looks neat on a scale of 1: 100 000. I use many arcgis tools to try to make it look neat but its never working reallly good....

[image]

I would like to get neat road segment like this picture. How can i do that?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Merge Divided Roads (Cartography)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000w000000) tool for this.

> Generates single-line road features in place of matched pairs of
>   divided road lanes. Matched pairs of roads or lanes are merged if they
>   are the same road class, trend generally parallel to one another, and
>   are within the merge distance apart. The road class is specified by
>   the Merge Field parameter. All nonmerged roads from the input
>   collection are copied to the output feature class.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Aaron, is there some prestep i need to do before i run this tool? each im having some errors message see the capture i join up there.

Comment: @SimonGIS Normally you should ask follow up questions as new questions to maintain our "one question per question" as mentioned in the [Tour].  In this instance I think you just need to run the Repair Geometry and Multipart To Singlepart tools first.