# Simplify networks from OSM in qgis

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, simplify

I want to make something like in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/simplifying-road-network-for-cartography) in QGIS.

In ArcGIS there is available [Make Divided Roads](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000w000000) plugin. Is there easy way to make the same job in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Related (unanswered) question here: [How can I merge/collapse nearby and parallel road lines (eg. a dual-carriageway) into one single line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/how-can-i-merge-collapse-nearby-and-parallel-road-lines-eg-a-dual-carriageway).

Start with valid singlepart geometries. I'd Buffer at a few different distances that seem appropriate (maybe based on road class too?). Then Dissolve to one buffered road. Now it gets trickier, you need to get centerlines from your polys, see ideas here: [Finding centrelines from polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis)